# Questions about Segment Heap

Tags: winapi, memory-management, windows-10-desktop

1. Does the new Windows 10 v2004 Segment Heap work on both 32-bit and 64-bit applications?
2. Does the Segment Heap manifest work on DLLs or only the top level .exe, i.e. is it at a module granularity or process granularity?

Comment: From documents, Windows 10, version 2004 (build 19041) and later is required, no other limitations mentioned. [Improving Memory Usage](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/06/17/improving-memory-usage/), [Application Manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests?source=docs#heaptype)

Comment: Can it be enabled on 32-bit x86 applications too, either with or without Large Address Aware?

Comment: You can try to enable for 32-bit application and check if the Segment Heap used through [`!heap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-heap) command.